# Why when I print RDLC dirctly on thermal POS printer it does not fit the size?

Tags: c#, rdlc

When I print a `.RDLC` report using print preview, it is working fine. But when I print it directly, it does not fit the size and it expands.

The text will show in very large size.

It happens only with thermal printers, but it is working fine with A4 laser printers.

Comment: Few days ago I updated my graphics card driver, and then all text of invoice became larger on thermal printer. I just removed and reinstalled old version of graphics card driver that fixed the issue. I don't know what graphics card driver did to my printer settings?